# Measure time required to create thread

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, boost, pthreads

How can I measure time required to create and launch thread?
(Linux, pthreads or boost::thread).

Thanks for advices!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve through this? Hopefully, you are not trying some optimization because you cant & its pointless to think of such an optimization.

Comment: I need perform some actions on non-regular basics - call function X after 30 ms, call function Y after 15 ms, call Z after 60 ms. This functions should send message in queue.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably specify what exactly you want to measure, since there are at least 2 possible interpretations (the time the original thread is "busy" inside `pthread_create` versus the time from calling `pthread_create` until the other thread actually executes its first instruction).

In either case, you can query monotonic real time using [`clock_gettime`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html) with `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` before and after the call to `pthread_create` or before the call and as the first thing inside the thread funciton. Then, subtract the second value from the first.

To know what time is spent inside `phtread_create`, `CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID` is an alternative, as this only counts the actual time your thread used.

Alltogether, it's a bit pointless to measure this kind of thing, however. It tells you *little to nothing at all* about how it will behave under real conditions on your system or another system, with unknown processes and unknown scheduling strategies and priorities.
On another machine, or on another day, your thread might just be scheduled 100 or 200 milliseconds later. If you depend on the fact that this won't happen, you're dead.

**EDIT:**
In respect of the info added in above comment, if you need to "perform actions on non-regular basis" on a scale that is well within "normal scheduling quantums", you can just create a single thread and `nanosleep` for 15 or 30 milliseconds. Of course, sleep is not terribly accurate or reliable, so you might instead want to e.g. block on a `timerfd` (if portability is not topmost priority, otherwise use a signal-delivering timer).
It's no big problem to schedule irregular intervals with a single timer/wait either, you only need to keep track of when the *next* event is due. This is how modern operating systems do it too (read up on "timer coalescing").

Comment: ..and, in many apps, is just N/A because it's a one-time cost at startup.

Comment: @MartinJames: Yep, it's only really interesting (if at all) for applications that use (non-kernel) aio, or getaddrinfo_a or libunbound or similar (all of which spawn threads at unpredictable times). And then, there's nothing you can do about it anyway...